# PHP: Get body of request received

Tags: php, api, post, http-headers

I am currently working with a 3rd party API which I cannot disclose. The summary is:

action -> 3rd party -> callback

So my server communicates with 3rd party with some data

Once the data is sent back, the 3rd party sends an XML to the callback url.

I am receiving the callback with the headers:

Content-type: application/xml
Content-length: 69
Request-method: POST

However, print_r($_POST) is showing nothing at all. Nor is $_GET.

What could be going on? I know you cannot give me the most detailed answer based on my vagueness but if you could point me in the right direction, that would be brilliant.

Comment: Remove the 3rd party from the equation and send data yourself in same format and confirm the same thing is happening.

Comment: $_GET/$_POST are only populated if the api's callback mechanism does a proper "html form" type submission. it may be sending the xml in a raw-unencapsulated format, in which case you have to read it directly from `php://input`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [php://input](http://php.net/wrappers.php) :

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Ok, so $post works and I can see the data there; how do I extract the individual items?